# chdir doesn't work in c

Tags: c, posix, chdir

I have a father process and a child process, the second created with fork, the child receive from the father a char s[] (s can be something like "cd Music" ), i extract Music from "cd Music" using strtok, but when chdir(dir) executes i get "No such file or directory". But if i test chdir("Music") i get no error. I want to change the working directory of the child process. Help me please...

```
 char *dir  = strtok(s," ");
 dir = strtok(NULL," ");
 if(chdir(dir) == -1){
    perror("Cannot change directory");    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no communication between the father and the child after the fork(). This (pseudo code) doesn't work:

```
int s[100];
if (fork()) {
    /* father */
    strcpy(s, "cd Music"); /* pass string to child -- NOT! */
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* use uninitialized s */
}
```

This works

```
int s[100] = "cd Music";
if (fork()) {
    /* father */
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* use children's copy of s */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the contents of dir. Maybe its value is not what you expected.

Comment: Or use `gdb` or whatever debugger he has available.